# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar un id HTML con node.js?

Tags: html, nodejs

El problema que tengo es el siguiente Cuando intento seleccionar un id de HTML con node.js mediante el código:

`document.getElementById("id");`

Me sale error por eso me preguntaba como podría hacerlo...

Comment: no lo puedes hacer con node, pues este solo sirve los archivos. Para tu caso tendrias que utilizar javascript

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Decir que tienes un error y no decir exactamente cual es el mensaje de error y cómo reproducirlo, es como habla por teléfono con el mecánico y decirle simplemente que el carro "no arranca", sin ningún tipo de detalle. Si hay un error, incluye información relacionada con el mismo, comenzando por el mensaje exacto de error (como texto), el trozo relevante indicando la línea de código donde salta el error y otra información del entorno/proceso que sea relevante.